# Docker Swarm with data: shared volume vs clustering vs single instance

Tags: database, elasticsearch, docker, redis, docker-swarm

I make my first steps with Docker Swarm and wonder how to deal with services that use persistent data like redis, elasticsearch or a database.

I found a lot of tutorials on how to configure redis/elasticsearch/database clusters with docker swarm - but isn't it easier to use a shared storage? E.g., I work with Azure, so I simpy could use a single Azure File Storage as a redis/elasticsearch/database volume and let all my nodes mount this File Storage.
Is this an acceptable approach or are there some significant disadvantages (for example, when two or more database instances try to write at the same time on that storage)?

Is it recommended at all to use such "data"-services in **every** node? Or should I use Docker Swarm just for frontend-services and have a single redis/elasticsearch/database service?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use a shared folder accessed from  more than one application instance than the application itself need to be designed in a way to avoid data corruption (no given file is written at the same time from more than application. So called mutex locks)

All databases that I know of are not designed this way so you can't use them with shared storage.

What they normally do instead is to connect all database in a cluster and the sync is done at a software level.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts! Right now I'm about planning a complex swarm cluster with various services which cannot be stateless. My findings are the same like yours: 1. Avoid using shared volumes 2. Use Cluster functionalty if the service provide it 3. Avoid using single instances of a service (in production) because of resilience reasons. Another thing I came around was the question: (e.g.) If one of my clustered databases dies, how should my node process from the same machine react to it? My answer: Mark the whole machine as "sick" so it should be completey unreachable and/or be restarted.

Comment: if you deploy the db container as a service you can use healthchecks , so if the container is really dead than docker swarm will kill it and spin up a new one which means only few seconds downtime

If you use mysql I am currently working on a very easy clustering solution so you can deploy many instances and they will all sync together using the gallera cluster so loosing one is not a problem

it is not ready yet , but maybe in few weeks time.
https://github.com/vipconsult/percona-docker/tree/master/pxc-57